# "true" value sent from $.post not being considered in the back-end

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm scratching my head over an issue that deals with true/false/null values, I tried several variations including type coercion, false, null etc.

Basically, when I click on someone's profile picture, this happens on the front-end:

```
var isProfilePhoto = false;

if ( $(this).data('profilephoto') === true ) {
  isProfilePhoto = true;
  photoId = parseInt( $(that).data('photoid') );
}

$.post('/mod', { isProfilePhoto: isProfilePhoto, photoId: photoId },
  function (data) {
    if (data.msg === 'delete pic success') {
      $(that).css({ opacity: 0 });
    } else {
      alert("There was a problem. Please contact the webmaster. ERROR CODE: " + data.msg);
    }
});
```

In the back-end, I have an if/else case that checks if it's profile photo, the if looks like:

```
  console.log(req.body.isProfilePhoto); // true
  if (req.body.isProfilePhoto == true) {
    ModModel.deletePhoto(photoId, function () {
      if (userIp !== null) {
        ModModel.banUserIP(userIp, function (response) { if (response === true) { return res.send('delete pic success') } } );
      } else {
        return res.send({msg: 'delete pic success'});
      }
    });
  } else {
    // other stuff
  }
```

However once in the back-end it goes to the else case, even if `req.body.isProfilePhoto` is true, it goes to the else case...

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but are you sure that the `true` you're sending/receiving remains `true` (Boolean) and not `'true'` (string)?

Comment: In the console it says just `true`, also wouldnt double-equal convert the string to just `true` if the value was indeed `"true"`?

Comment: @DanyP No. Strings are "truthy" values, but that does not make them equal to `true`. `if("true")` and `if("true" == true)` are not equivalent.

Comment: Having tried in Chrome's console, `'true' == true` returns `false`, so no: there's no type coercion (which makes sense, really). If, however, it reports `true` in the console then it's almost certainly a Boolean `true`.

Comment: @DanyP `"true" == true => false`

Comment: Ah, right, I just changed == true to == 'true' in the backend and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know that the `true` from the front-end gets converted to a string `"true"`, not sure why that would happen...

Comment: @DanyP Jordan's answer sums it up; you're not passing data, you're passing string parameters. When you GET or POST urlencoded forms all you can send are strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is going to make a POST request with the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and a POST body that looks like this:

```
isProfilePhoto=true&photoId=123
```

Your server receives that as a string (well, a byte stream...) and unless you have code or some module that tells it otherwise, it has no way to know that the four bytes `true` should be converted to a boolean, or that the three bytes `123` should be converted to a number (it's probable that your ORM takes care of the latter at some point, though).

One way to get around this would be to send a JSON request instead. (In jQuery you do this by passing `"json"` as the 4th argument to `$.post`). In such a request the Content-Type would be `application/json` and the POST body would look like this (except without the whitespace):

```
{ "isProfilePhoto": true,
  "photoId":        123 }
```

In JSON, `true` is always a boolean and `"true"` is always a string, so when your server parses it it'll automatically have the right type. Of course, you'd have to change your server-side code to parse the JSON body, but that's pretty easy these days.